Issue with emitting 'updateLiveId' event in Socket.IO when using Express.js server
I'm encountering an issue with emitting the 'updateLiveId' event in my Socket.IO setup when using an Express.js server. The problem arises when I execute the '/test-route' endpoint, either from Postman or my React frontend. Although I can see that the "Accessed /test-route" log is being generated in the server console, the 'updateLiveId' event is not being triggered as expected.
I'm using Socket.IO version "socket.io": "^4.7.2".
Here's a breakdown of the situation:

When a user connects to the Socket.IO server, the server logs "A user is connected" successfully.
If I emit the 'updateLiveId' event directly from my HTML file, it works as expected.

However, I need to emit the 'updateLiveId' event from the server side, after performing some queries, which is not working.
Here's a snippet of my server-side code:
import 'dotenv/config';
import express from 'express';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import 'express-async-errors';
import http from 'http';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import Startdb from './config/startup/db';
import Routes from './restAPIs/routes';
import passport from 'passport';
import * as path from 'path';
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(httpServer);

Startdb();

// Express middleware setup
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public')));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Passport setup
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Routes setup
Routes(app);

// Socket.IO connection handling
io.on('connection', (socket: any) => {
  console.log('A user is connected');

  socket.on('updateLiveId', ({ liveId }: any) => {
    console.log("Emit data...", liveId);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(`socket ${socket.id} disconnected`);
  });
});

// Endpoint to trigger the issue
app.get('/test-route', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Accessed /test-route');
  io.emit('updateLiveId', { liveId: 'VJLaSy0hlVI' });
  res.send('Event emitted successfully');
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

I have verified that the server is able to connect to Socket.IO and emit events, as evidenced by the "A user is connected" log and successful event emission from the HTML file. However, emitting the 'updateLiveId' event from the server side, particularly within the '/test-route' endpoint, does not produce the expected result.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I troubleshoot and resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
